# Joining tables where data is not present or links not obvious

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables

- Earnings
- Internal Contributions
- External Contributions

**Earnings**

```
Dateended       |Salary 
31/03/2020      |40000.00
31/03/2019      |39000.00
31/03/2018      |38000.00
31/03/2017      |37000.00
```

**IntContributions**

```
Datereceived   |Amount
31/03/2020      |1500.00
31/03/2019      |1400.00
31/03/2018      |1300.00
31/03/2017      |1200.00
```

**ExtContributions**

```
Datepaid        |Contribution
31/03/2019      |500.00
31/03/2017      |500.00
```

I am able to join Earnings and Internal Contributions by `earnings.dateended = intcontributions.datereceived`

I also want to join with Extcontributions but when I use `AND earnings.dateended = extcontributions.datepaid` I get a return of

```
31/03/2019 | 1400.00 | 500.00
31/03/2017 | 1200.00 | 500.00
```

What I would like to see is data as at each date with a blank or zero in extcontributions when the data does not exist in the table

I'm using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, and show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOINS`:

```
select
  e.dateended
  e.salary
  i.amount
  ext.contribution
from earnings e
left join intcontributions i
on e.folderid = i.folderid and e.dateended = i.datereceived
left join extcontributions ext
on e.folderid = ext.folderid and e.dateended = ext.datepaid
```